# FASTQ file trimming

Tags: fastq

I have a FASTQ file:

```
@NS500455:80:HG7TNBGXB:1:11101:17723:1055 1:N:0:ATCACG
ACTTANGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTGTATAGGGATCCNAGCTCCAATTCGCCCTATAGTGAGTCGTAT
+
/AAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@NS500455:80:HG7TNBGXB:1:11101:8821:1057 1:N:0:ATCACG
ACTTANGTGATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTGTATAATAAATATCTAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCCGAACTCCA
```

I want to remove the string  ACTTAAGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTG from it while retaining the sequences starting from TA onwards.
I wrote `grep "ACTTAAGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTGTA" SRR_1.fastq | sed "s/ACTTAAGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTGTA/TA/g"`, but it removes the headers of the FASTQ file as well.

The desired output would be

```
@NS500455:80:HG7TNBGXB:1:11101:17723:1055 1:N:0:ATCACG
TATAGGGATCCNAGCTCCAATTCGCCCTATAGTGAGTCGTAT
+
/AAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@NS500455:80:HG7TNBGXB:1:11101:8821:1057 1:N:0:ATCACG
TATAATAAATATCTAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCCGAACTCCA
```

How to do this. I dont want to use cutadapt.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 4):

What application are you using that will be okay with a mismatching quality string?

Use trimmomatic or cutadapt, or bcl2fastq could probably do the job too.  Those will also have the benefit of dealing properly with one-off errors, which awk and sed won't.

Answer (score 3):

Skip the `grep`, use just the `sed`. Unless the header contains the long sequence as well (which I doubt it will), your command will work.

```
sed 's/^ACTTAAGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTGTA/TA/' SRR_1.fastq > SRR_1.edited.fastq
```

Comment: It works but there are some sequences begining with: ACTTANGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTG They are being retained. How to deal with them. Kindly guide.

Comment: That's because `N` does not match A,T,C or G as a literal. Replace all `N` with `[ATCG]` to remove these sequences.

Comment: It is worth considering thomas' point. If you'd like your QUAL lines to reflect the change to the SEQ lines. awk or bioawk might be better at this point.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the quality vector for each read, then your code will create a shift because it does not cut the quality vector. You should rather use a trimming tool a systematically cut all 33 first characters. **[fastp](https://github.com/OpenGene/fastp)** will allow you to do it easily with the `-f, --trim_front1` argument.

Comment: What should be the command line , I typed fastp -i SRR_1.fastq -o trimSRR1.fq -f 33 and it gives an error ERROR: trim_front1 (--trim_front1) should be 0 ~ 30, suggest 0 ~ 4. Kindly help.

Comment: strange! I did'nt know it was restricted to 30. You can run fastp twice with 20 in the first trimming and 13 in second one? not really convenient but it should work!

Comment: you may alternatively had a look at Trimmomatic (http://www.usadellab.org/cms/?page=trimmomatic). It has a `HEADCROP` argument, but I don't know if it also restricted in length.